# Docker Airflow cannot access Spark in Windows

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, airflow

I have a Airflow running via docker. I am using a [docker compose file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) from apache airflow documents. My Spark is installed in Windows environment and the Spark is accessible via command line. If I run `spark-submit file.py` then the spark returns the result. However, when I put that file as a `dag` in airflow it shows error as below.

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/rawdatadropdown.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/rawdatadropdown.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

My understanding is that Airflow is not able to access pyspark. Any help of how to fix it is really appreciated.
The airflow code is below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from createconnection import connection
from datetime import datetime
import os

# Define the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 5, 9),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'pyspark_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple DAG to run a PySpark script every 2 minutes',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=2)
)

# Define the task
def run_pyspark_script():
    url, uname, pwd = connection()
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").getOrCreate()
    try:
        jdbcDF = spark.read \
                .format("jdbc") \
                .option("url", url) \
                .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
                .option("query", '''SELECT TOP 100 t1.TBNAME as Experiment, 
                                    t2.TBYEAR as EXP_YEAR, 
                                    t4.TBFLDNAME as TRAITNAME 
                                    FROM dbo.EXP01 as t1 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.EXP05 as t2 ON t1.TBID=t2.TBEXPTID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.EXP02 as t3 ON t1.TBID=t3.TBEXPTID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.TRD01 as t4 ON t3.TBTRAITID=t4.TBID
                 ''') \
                .option("user", uname) \
                .option("password", pwd) \
                .load()
        
        # Write the output to a CSV file
        output_file = f"path/to/output_{datetime.now().
                        strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}.csv"
        if not os.path.exists(output_file):
            with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
                f.write('Experiment,EXP_YEAR,TRAITNAME\n')
        jdbcDF.write.csv(output_file, header=True, mode='append')
        
        spark.stop()
    except ValueError as error:
        print("Connector write failed", error)

run_script_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_pyspark_script',
    python_callable=run_pyspark_script,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Spark is installed on your Windows OS but if you want to use it via Airflow you need to install it in your Airflow docker container.

add this in your dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-spark
```

Comment: Thank you for informing. However, I am not using windows for Spark and airflow. I am using linux now. Because I found that docker is actually a linux machine/kernel running in the background. So instead of having a subsystem for airflow if I move the whole thing to linux it will be easier for me. But thank you again.

Comment: So now it's ok? because as I know you must install your packages in the container to let it work. every docker container is like a separate VM with separate memory. (not dependent on the type of the base OS you run).

Comment: Yes. Since I am running it in Red Hat OS I am not using docker as I have installed it in host OS instead of using a VM such as docker. The only problem with windows was that airflow is not supported in windows therefore I was using docker. But using docker for airflow and spark in the host system needs a work-around. You need to mount the folder where Spark is installed in host inside the docker vm for airflow to access it.